# Add expires headers - gtmetrix

Tags: .htaccess

There are 5 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins%3A300%2Cregular%2C500%2C600%2C700%2Clatin-ext%2Clatin%2Cdevanagari&ver=1.0.0
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins%3A700%2C300&ver=1581165984
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:700%2C300%2C400%7CRoboto:400%2C900
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%3Aregular%2C700&ver=6.0.5
https://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?v=ext&j=1%3A8.1.1&blog=167300497&post=1633&tz=0&srv=alshuwaifatmarbles.com&host=alshuwaifatmarbles.com&ref=&fcp=2042&rand=0.1473167431208402
```

Comment: You can't add response headers to external resources. Don't take all of gtmetrix "suggestions" as _gospel_.

Comment: Can you clarify what question is being asked here?